# Creating Lego-style hair in Blender

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create Lego-style hair in Blender, but I'm unsure how to achieve the desired effect. I want the hair to appear as a single, solid piece, like a molded plastic part. However, it currently looks more like a collection of separate elements.

Here's what I've done so far:

- I've sculpted the base for the hair.
- I've created individual curls using curves, and added custom bevel profiles.
- I've combined all the objects and converted them to a mesh (while also saving backups).

Does anyone know how I can merge these objects to make them look like a single, cohesive piece, resembling real Lego hair?

[image: this is how my work looks now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remesh and Smooth

Starting from the point where the hair is made out of curves:

Convert to a mesh with *Object > Convert > Mesh* or search for "convert" in the F3 command palette.

[image: convert curve to mesh]

Switch to the *Sculpting* workspace and use the voxel remesher to merge the hair strips. for the scale I'm working I used a *Voxel Size* of `0.05m` but your resolution may need to be different.

[image: voxel remesh lego hair]

Use the *Smooth Brush* with a large brush size and a low strength to eliminate remeshing artifacts and further merge the hair strips.

[image: sculpt smooth lego hair]

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! Your response is very helpful; it's the solution I had in mind, but I didn't know how to do it because I'm not very familiar with Blende